# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
(cdn_url = "", LazyLoad.js("maps/map0.js" {maps_loaded[0] = true}))
```

It keeps saying Uncaught `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

It now says it is missing `[`

Whole line:

```
if (("" == window.location.port || "80" == window.location.port) && !/\/wiki/.test(window.location.pathname)) window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":" + config.http_port + window.location.pathname;
var map = [],
    on_map = [],
    maps_loaded = {}, cdn_url = "localhost";
"80" != window.location.port ? (cdn_url = "", LazyLoad.js("maps/map0.js", {
    maps_loaded[0] = true
})) {
    maps_loaded[0] = true
})) : LazyLoad.js(cdn_url + "maps/map0.js?" + map_hashes[0], function () {
    maps_loaded[0] = true
});
```

Comment: mal-formed json string, most likely. show what you're fetching, or try running it through jsonlint.org

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427372/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier)

Comment: You have asked the same question yesterday. I guess I gave you quite straightforward answer.

Comment: I did but this is another error :(

Comment: `LazyLoad.js("maps/map0.js" {maps_loaded[0]=true})` you're missing a comma in your parameter list.

Comment: @Jeroen: Stackoverflow is not your personal debugger. That's what developer tools are for. Use JSHint (http://www.jshint.com/) and read basic JS tutorials if you don't have a good idea of the JavaScript syntax yet.

Answer (score 4):

Do you need a comma after:

```
"maps/map0.js"
```

and before:

```
{maps_loaded[0]=true}
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Form what I see - you are missing coma after first argument passed to LazyLoad.js function -> it should be (cdn_url="",LazyLoad.js("maps/map0.js", {maps_loaded[0]=true}))

Comment: Gives me another error now says its missing [